# Bind Gesture Recognizers

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to Bind a Gesture Recognizer in Xml so I can handle when an Item is clicked

I tried using this for my XML

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextPostTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor = "Black" FontSize = "15"/>
                        <Image Source="options_icon.png" HeightRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="{Binding OptionClick}"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Body}" TextColor = "Black"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I try binding it to

```
 foreach (var post in posts)
        {
      TapGestureRecognizer optionsClick = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            optionsClick.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                ShowPostOptions(page, navigation, post.id, post.user);
            };
}
```

and...

`OptionClick = optionsClick`

But I get

> .xaml : error : Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are effectively binding an instance of `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `Tapped` event. You cannot data-bind an event and also if you would set it, you would set it to an event handler not an instance of the `TapGestureRecognizer` itself.

You have two options - either **Event Handler** or a **Command**.

### Event Handler

Declare the gesture recognizer in XAML as follows:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TappedHandler" />
```

And create an event handler called `TappedHandler` in code-behind of the page:

```
public void TappedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ShowPostOptions(page, navigation, post.id, post.user);
}
```

### Command

Declare the gesture recognizer in XAML as follows:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
```

And create a command in your view model, that will handle the tap:

```
private ICommand _tapCommand;

public ICommand TapCommand => _tapCommand ?? 
     ( _tapCommand = new Command( 
          () => ShowPostOptions(page, navigation, post.id, post.user) ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to bind an event to a command, then seemingly back again, and its just not going to work

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="{Binding OptionClick}"/>
```

---

If you have a ICommand in your view model you can do this

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" ...
```

---

If you have an event ready to go in code behind you can do this

```
public void OnTapGestureRecognizerTappedEvet(Object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    // code here
}

<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTappedEvet" ...
```

---

if you want to do it all in code you can do this

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

---

[Adding a Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/)